# How other systems will recognize my PYTHONPATH since it isn't provided?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, module, package

I'm coding a bot.
In this bot, deep in the program directory structure, I have to make an import that needs the absolute path of a package far away in the directory structure. In a way that I can't make the imports.

I've managed to import it successfully by exporting the PYTHONPATH variable in my local ~/.bashrc file containing the absolute path to my package.

Then I can import things in my program like:

```py
import absolute_path.module
```

The thing is, when someone else downloads this program files for use, or when I upload it to a server, how is this other party going to manage this absolute importing I made? (Provided the package to be imported is going along with the program files, in the same path where I make the importing).
They didn't set the PYTHONPATH variable, so, are they going to have troubles?

Answer (score 0):

It depends. Is the other module something standard (ie installable via pip etc)? then you just add it to your project's [requirements.txt](https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/1.1/requirements.html) and the users should be able to figure it out from there.

If it's something you've written, then you can use something like [PyInstaller](https://pypi.org/project/PyInstaller/) to package all the dependencies of your module (including imports and even the python interpreter) so users don't need to download anything extra.

Another option is to put the other module with your bot module and distribute them together, and use relative paths.

Comment: It's something I've written, but it's placed in a folder where I can't reach it by an import try inside a specific file.  
It only works when I set the PYTHONPATH to look for that package.  
This other module is with my bot module.

Answer (score 0):

Make your bot into an [installable package](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/)